# React Native and Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, react-native

I'm very new to API, and recently I started learning React Native and found some quick tutorial about RN frontend and Laravel backend just App just to show how is API working between. So I done everything step by step but my data from laravel, server is not fetching... Here is my whole code

Starting from Laravel first
This is my `CoinController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Coin;

class CoinController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $coins = Coin::all();

        return response()->json($coins);
    }
}
```

Here is my migration for coin table:

```
class CreateCoinsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('coins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('coins');
    }
}
```

Here is my `api.php` file:

```
Route::get('coins', 'CoinController@index');
```

And here is my `env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sqFYSTaGklMTMtSFjRWQjKbIfhPWiGFq1p3JzJOdfOg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=routingproj
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

And now React Native app
Here is my `App.js`

```
// App.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import Coin from './src/screens/Coin';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  CoinScreen: {screen: Coin},
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

My `Coin.js`

```
// Coin.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import ajax from '../services/FetchCoins';
import CoinList from '../components/CoinList';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#B6A6BB',
  },
});

export class Coin extends Component {
  state = {
    coins: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const coins = await ajax.FetchCoins();
    this.setState({coins});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.coins.length > 0 ? (
          <CoinList coins={this.state.coins} />
        ) : (
          <Text>No coins</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Coin;
```

Here is my `FetchCoin.js`

```
// FetchCoins.js

const URI = 'http://my_ip_address/routingproj/public/api/coins';

export default {
  async fetchCoins() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(URI + '/api/coins');
      let responseJsonData = await response.json();
      return responseJsonData;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
};
```

And my `CoinList.js`

```
// CoinList.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class CoinList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    coins: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.coinsList}>
        {this.props.coins.map(coin => {
          return (
            <View key={coin.id}>
              <Text style={styles.cointext}>
                {coin.name} | {coin.price}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  coinsList: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  cointext: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

That is all of my code and when i run `react-native run-android`
it shows me No Coins, so that mean my data from server doesn't fetch.
Any solutions?

Comment: Sidenote: You posted the same block of code for `CoinController` and your migration.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I edited it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your laravel response from browser or Postman, if it's okey, please check fetchCoin.js file becouse as I understand it your API endpoint is repeated.

Your URI value is finished with **/api/coins** but at the bottom line you used as fetch(URI + **'api/coins'** )

so it's mean `/api/coins + /api/coins`

as a result you are trying to fetch data from an incorrect URL;

`http://my_ip_address/routingproj/public/api/coins/api/coins`

// FetchCoins.js

```
const URI = 'http://my_ip_address/routingproj/public/api/coins';

export default {
  async fetchCoins() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(URI + '/api/coins');
      let responseJsonData = await response.json();
      return responseJsonData;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm doing it right now, sorry for my late respond Sir !

Comment: So i changed it like this ```const URI = 'http://my_ip_address/routingproj/public``` and on my ```fetch``` I leave everything same so ```(URI + '/api/coins');``` but nothing happend... On my android emulator it still shows me No Coins. I checked my laravel response from browser and it's okay, when I route my browser to ```localhost/routingproj/public/api/coins``` it shows me all my data from server. Sir is there any more solutions?

Comment: It's also shows me this warning:
```Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): Type Error:_FetchCoins.default.FetchCoins is not a function. (In '_FetchCoins.default.FetchCoins()', '_FetchCoins.default.FetchCoins is undefined)```

Comment: Okay for this warning I fix my mistake, it was ```async fetchCoins()``` it has to be ```async FetchCoins()```. But it still shows me **No Coins**

Comment: Okay so now it shows me just **No Coins** without any warnings, but after some time, maybe 20 seconds it throws me this: ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.coins.length') This error is located at: in Coin (at SceneView.js:9)```. What is this ?